# How to Generate keystore.p12 from Certificate(.cer) , certificate chain(.p7b) and from key(.key and .pem)

Tags: ssl, openssl, keystore

I have the following files:

- filename.key (RSA PRIVATE KEY)
- filename.pem (CERTIFICATE REQUEST)
- certificate.cer (CERTIFICATE)
- CertificateChain.p7b

I have received these files from the CA including the certificate chain.
I need to generate 'keystore.p12' to configure SSL for spring boot application with the following information.

```
 server:
    port: 443
    ssl:
        key-store: keystore.p12
        key-store-password: <your-password>
        keyStoreType: PKCS12
        keyAlias: <my alias>
```

Can anyone please help me to generate the 'keystore.p12'?

Answer (score 1):

File extensions do not actually control the format or contents a file, although *usually* they *should* provide at least *partial* description. Similarly basenames (before the extension) *should* describe what is in the file, but do not always do so correctly. What matters is what is in the files.

`.key` is usually used for a lone privatekey, but look at it to make sure, and also to determine what format it is in because there are many. You should *never* get your privatekey from a CA; it should be generated locally, usually on the machine where it will be used and at least by the 'owner' or admin of that machine. There might be a sort-of exception if you are talking about a CA internal to a company, organization, agency, or office -- in that case the person running the CA may be the same person who is responsible for security on all the machines -- or vice versa, depending on your perspective -- and it may make sense for them to generate both the key and the cert.

`.pem` is used for *lots* of things in [PEM format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-Enhanced_Mail), and what the contents of that file is (or are) matters more than the fact of it being PEM. Look at the first line `-----BEGIN (somewords)-----` and see what the word(s) is(are). That should be followed either immediately or after a few header lines by data in base64 (a solid block of letters, digits, and the special characters + / =), then a matching `-----END (somewords)-----` line. If the END line is followed by a another similar block, or several, look at all of them.

`.cer` is commonly used for certificates in either 'DER' (binary) or 'PEM' (as above) format. `.p7b` is similarly used for 'dummy' PKCS7 messages containing certificates -- especially certificates used in a chain -- in either DER or PEM. More significantly, p7b is sometimes used for the whole chain *including* the end-entity (server) cert, and sometimes the rest of the chain *excluding* the EE cert, and it matters which. If you have OpenSSL -- or can get it (e.g. by installing a package, or for Windows I recommend the installer from http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html ) or can move your data to a machine that has it -- then do:

```
 # if the p7b file is in PEM format (you can see ----BEGIN PKCS7----- line)
 openssl pkcs7 -in file.p7b -print_certs 
 # if the p7b file is in DER format (looks like garbage in a text editor or display)
 openssl pkcs7 -in file.p7b -inform der -print_certs
 # for now look only at the subject= and issuer= lines to see
 # for each cert in the file who it is for, and if/how they chain
```

Then:

- if the `.key` file is a privatekey in one of the PEM formats supported by OpenSSL you can use that; else if `.key` is a privatekey in some other format, or `.pem` is or includes a privatekey in some format, you'll need to convert and/or extract it: tell us more about what those files look like.
- if the `.p7b` file is in PEM or DER format, put its expanded output (from above) in a file. If this includes the EE cert skip the next step.
- if the `.p7b` file does not include the EE cert, but the `.cer` file is that cert, if in PEM format just append it to the file containing the `.p7b` output; if in DER format convert it with `openssl x509 -in file.cer -inform der` and append *that*.
- if you now have the privatekey in one of the PEM formats supported by OpenSSL, and the cert chain including the EE cert in PEM format, do

```
    openssl pkcs12 -export -in chain.pem -inkey key.pem -out newfile.p12 [-name x]
    # the -name option provides the 'alias' used by Java
    # if not specified it defaults to the numeral 1 (one)
```

Comment: thanks for your useful description. I tried to update the key/certificate description in the original problem text. Plus executing the command on p7b(in DER format) I get multiple CERTIFICATE blocks. Maybe it will give you some other clue to help me more specifically.  Thanks again!

Comment: Okay, RSA PRIVATE KEY satisfies my point 1 (it is an OpenSSL-usable format) and CERTIFICATE REQUEST is irrelevant now so ignore that. It matters _which_ cert(s) you have, in both certificate.cer and chain.p7b. As I said look first at the subject= and issuer= lines from the `pkcs7 -print_certs` command; plus add `openssl x509 -noout -subject -issuer -in certificate.cer`. Depending on which is where, see my points 2-4.